# Redirect to the browse files screen pentaho when logging in

Tags: pentaho

I want to set browse files page as home page for Pentaho BI server. 
By default we need to click on Browse files button to see our files. I want see my files in my home page

Can anybody please help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.)  Open `pentaho-solutions/system/default-plugin/plugin.xml` file in a Text editor. 
2.)  Change the `browser.perspective layout-priority` from -1 to -3 as follows:

From:

```
<perspective id="browser.perspective" title="${browse}" layout-priority="-1" 
               resourcebundle="content/default-plugin/resources/messages/messages" content-url="mantle/browser">
```

To:

```
<perspective id="browser.perspective" title="${browse}" layout-priority="-3" 
               resourcebundle="content/default-plugin/resources/messages/messages" content-url="mantle/browser">
```

The lowest number is displayed to the users when they log in.

Note: After following the above steps, Restart the BA-Server